# FireBase account / Free plan limitits

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase in a web application, I would understand the limtation of free plan.

For Realtime Database the "GB downloaded" is 10 GB 
What does that mean ?
10 GB per month ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is per month.

> What if I exceed my Spark or Flame plan limits?
>
> In order to provide you a predictable price, the resources available
>   to you in Spark and Flame plans are capped. This means that when you
>   exceed **any plan limit** in **any month**, your app will be turned off, to
>   prevent any further resource usage and additional charges.
>
> Usage is measured monthly, and if your app is disabled in a given
>   month, it will be re-enabled automatically at the beginning of the
>   following month.
>
> We will attempt to notify you by e-mail as you approach your resource
>   limits. Of course, this may not be possible if a sudden spike in usage
>   occurs. In order to avoid caps altogether, upgrade to the Blaze plan,
>   which has no fixed resource limits.